# How to use jQuery replaceWith to replace varying number elements

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I have a varying number of elements with the same class name:

```
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
```

I want to replace each of these with a new set of elements with the same class name, but there could be more or fewer elements:

```
<p class="test"></p>
```

or

```
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
```

If I use `$('p.test').replaceWith('new content')`, it will replace each element with the content so I can't do that.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

EDIT (another explanation):

So I have these elements on the page:

```
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
```

Then, I dynamically retrieve a new set of elements (a varying number of them) that have the same class name (and maybe some other class names).  For example:

```
<p class="test classa"></p>
<p class="test classb"></p>
```

In the above example, I want the first three `<p>` elements to be gone. And in their place should be the 2 dynamically retreived `<p>` elements.

Keep in mind the number of elements of either set can vary.

Comment: Why do they have the same class? If you want each to have different elements you should use different id's. Or append new elements on the fly with jquery. I dont quite understand your question, could you please explain a little better? Thanks :)

Comment: They have the same class because that's how they are styled (not something I have control over). I cannot add ids because I don't have the ability to change the markup.  I could `.remove()` and `.append()` if that's my only option, but I was curious about a more elegant solution.

Comment: Added a new answer, maybe that will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

assuming you have your `<p>'s` into a container

```
<div id="container">
    <p class="test"></p>
    <p class="test"></p>
    <p class="test"></p>
    <p class="test"></p>
</div>
```

You could delete them, and append (or prepend) the new elements

```
$('p.test').remove(); //Will remove all <p>'s with class test
```

I assume your new set of elements are into the **data** array

```
var data= { 
  '1': '<p class="newclass">Hello</p>', 
  '2': '<p class="newclass2">Hello2</p>' 
  '3': '<p class="newclass3">Hello3</p>' 
  }; //Could have 100 rows, it wouldn't matter

$.each(data, function(i,val){   
        //Do some stuff
        $('#container').append(val);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, however, this won't work because if there are 3 elements returned in the 'p.test' selector, it will replace each one with 'new content'.  and 'new content' could be any number of 'p.test' elements. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Let me see if I get it, you want to replace an element with another element? Can you explain yourself a bit more? Use examples if you can :)

Comment: No, I want to replace many elements with a new set of elements which are retrieved dynamically. I thought my example in the question was good enough, but I'll try to update it.

Comment: They are not inside a surrounding div.  The tags I want to replace have many siblings that do not match what I want to replace.  I was trying to avoid removing and appending but maybe that's my only route

Answer (score 0):

$('p.test') is an array, you can loop in it

Comment: Technically, it's a jQuery object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a surrounding `<div>` and just replace that div with your new set of elements each time. So:

```
<div id="surround">
  <p class="test"></p>
  <p class="test"></p>
  <p class="test"></p>
</div>
```

Then jQuery:

```
$("#surround").replaceWith('new content');
```

Comment: I don't have access to change the markup so I can't add a surrounding div :/